# Keywords idea search with java api

Tags: java, api, google-ads-api

question about how to use adwords API (java). I searched on SO and other sources for similar question, but I could not find anything.

I use the adwords to search for "keywords idea", as shown in the joint image.

Now I wonder if/how is possible to get the list of suggestions ("keywords by relevance", at the bottom of the image, starting with "best sushi in new york"), using my keyword ("sushi new york", at the top) via adwords java API.

Toghether with the list, I would also like to have the fields on the left ("Avg monthly searches", "Competition", etc.) for every suggested keywords.

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

I link the image because I cannot attach it here (I am a new user).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4d7z.jpg

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service...I believe this is the same targeting service that you are looking to consume.